# Why is this code printing a bunch of empty lists and then an IndexError?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am iterating through a list (it may look unorganized, but there is a  reason) that is organized by: Dish name, # of ingredients, owner, ingredient 1, Description of ingredient 1, ingredient 2, description of ingredient 2, ingredient 3... etc. Each dish might have a different amount of ingredients, but that number of ingredients is always on the index after the dish name. Below is the list called book:

```
['pbj', 3, 'Alex', 'peanutbutter', 'Nice and Creamy', 'jelly', 
'Make sure it is refridgerated', 'bread', 'Whole wheat', 'Spaghetti', 
2, 'Ryan', 'noodles', 'Spaghetti shaped', 'tomato sauce', 'Smooth, not chunky',
'Grilled Cheese', 2, 'Jason', 'Cheese', 'Any kind of cheese', 'bread', 
'Any kind of bread']
```

I am getting an output of a couple lists and then an IndexError.

I have tried walking through step by step on what is happening in the process and I still do not understand the problem.

```
numDish = 3 

m = 0
for i in range (numDish): # for each unique dish
    k = m + 3
    print(book[m: k]) #prints dish, # of ingredients, and owner

    for j in range(int(book[m + 1])): #run for each ingredient per dish
        print(book[k: k + 2]) #print ingredient and associated description
        k += 2 
    print ('\n')
    m = k + 1 #Set m to the value after the last description
```

I want and expect the results to be printed as:

```
'pbj', 3, 'Alex'
'peanutbutter', 'Nice and Creamy', 
'jelly', 'Make sure it is refridgerated', 
'bread', 'Whole wheat', 

'Spaghetti', 2, 'Ryan', 
'noodles', 'Spaghetti shaped', 
'tomato sauce', 'Smooth, not chunky', 

'Grilled Cheese', 2, 'Jason', 
'Cheese', 'Any kind of cheese', 
'bread', 'Any kind of bread'
```

(Im not sure if it will have quotes or not but that doesn't matter to me.)

instead I get this:

```
['pbj', 3, 'Alex']
['peanutbutter', 'Nice and Creamy']
['jelly', 'Make sure it is refridgerated']
['bread', 'Whole wheat']
[2, 'Ryan', 'noodles']
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>    runfile('C:/Users/CSANCH08/Desktop/untitled2.py', wdir='C:/Users/CSANCH08/Desktop')
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site- packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 786, in runfile
>     execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site- packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
>     exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "C:/Users/CSANCH08/Desktop/untitled2.py", line 22, in 
>   for j in range(int(book[m + 1])): #run for each ingredient per dish
>
> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Ryan'

Comment: There is something in your book variable causing it to be a value error it looks like.

Comment: you're trying to convert `Ryan` to an integer. Check where you're applying `int` to some data in your code

Comment: You might want to think about making your variable naming a bit clearer - m and k aren't particularly intuitive for anyone reading the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
book = ['pbj', 3, 'Alex', 'peanutbutter', 'Nice and Creamy', 'jelly', 'Make sure >it is refridgerated', 'bread', 'Whole wheat', 'Spaghetti', 2, 'Ryan', 'noodles', 'Spaghetti shaped', 'tomato sauce', 'Smooth, not >chunky', 'Grilled Cheese', 2, 'Jason', 'Cheese', 'Any kind of >cheese', 'bread', 'Any kind of bread']
numDish = 3 

m = 0
for i in range (numDish): # for each unique dish
    k = m + 3
    print(book[m: k]) #prints dish, # of ingredients, and owner

    for j in range(int(book[m + 1])): #run for each ingredient per dish
        print(book[k: k + 2]) #print ingredient and associated description
        k += 2 
    print ('\n')
    m = k
```

in the last line change m=k+1 to m= k.

Comment: Song a long question for such a short solution. Worked like a charm, thanks!

Comment: So why is that the solution?

Comment: if you would dry run the code you would realize this but I ll try to explain anyway. 

when you print book[k:k+2] you are printing the values k and k+1. the k+2 value isn't printed or processed. so K+2 value is the next value that has to be used as m hence m=k and not m=k+1. 

I hope this explains it.